# Loop through array and evaluate expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS. I have the following syntax which I need to loop through array.

```
  {
    text: newcol[4],
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
      dt.order([[4, "desc"]]).draw();
    }
  }
```

Let's say I have an array `var nOrder = [4,5];` I want the following syntax to be generated - above syntax is getting repeated twice (as per length of array) and taking values 4 and 5.

```
buttons = [
  {
    text: newcol[4],
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
      dt.order([[4, "desc"]]).draw();
    }
  },
  {
    text: newcol[5],
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
      dt.order([[5, "desc"]]).draw();
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: *"I have the following syntax which I need to loop through array."* see [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: How is this related to jquery? Even if there is some in the background, it seems to be irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need? I don't think you need to use JQuery.

```
function generateSyntax(array) { // The argument should be an array such as [4, 5]
    var resultSyntax = ""; // Every time you loop through the array, add some syntax here.

    resultSyntax += "buttons = [\n";
    for (var i in array) {
        resultSyntax += `  {
    text: newcol[` + array[i] + `],
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
      dt.order([[` + array[i] + `, "desc"]]).draw();
    }
  },\n`; // Add the syntax, with the number in between brackets ("[" and "]")
    }
    resultSyntax += "];"
    return resultSyntax;
}
```

If you want to get it as an actual array, you can use this (which is slower but safe):

```
function generateSyntax(array) { // The argument should be an array such as ["4", 5, "2"]
    var resultSyntax = ""; // Every time you loop through the array, add some syntax here.

    resultSyntax += "buttons = [\n";
    for (var i in array) {
        resultSyntax += `  {
    text: newcol[` + (parseInt(array[i] + "") != parseInt(array[i] + "") ? 0 : parseInt(array[i] + "")) + `],
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
      dt.order([[` + (parseInt(array[i] + "") != parseInt(array[i] + "") ? 0 : parseInt(array[i] + "")) + `, "desc"]]).draw();
    }
  },\n`; // Add the syntax, with the number in between brackets ("[" and "]")
    }
    resultSyntax += "];"
    return resultSyntax;
}
```

At the location of where you want to unpack the buttons object, use

```
// ... assign the newcol array and the dt.order function
var buttons;
eval(generateSyntax(myArrayToParse));
// do stuff with the resultant buttons variable.
```

This will change all non-number parameters to `generateSyntax` to 0, to make the `eval` call safer. As a result, `generateSyntax` will accept both number and string parameters.

Comment: Thanks a ton. How can we convert from string to array?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted a string. Sorry!

Comment: The problem is, `newcol[index]` is an expression, which will be evaluated once only. When do you want to evaluate it?

Comment: I want to use it in DT library for creation of button. It does not take this as a string